# Questions about Qt Virtual Keyboard

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Creator 3.4.2 (Enterprise) and the Qt Version is 5.5.0. I'm pretty new to virtual keyboard, and I'm not familiar with QML. I have follow questions:

1. When I use `dialog.exec()`, the virtual keyboard can't work. What is the true method to implement a dialog when I need it to return a result.
2. When the lineedit is near the bottom of the screen, the virtual keyboard will cover the lineedit, and users can't know what they just typed. Can I resize or move the virtual keyboard or any other idea to solve this problem.

Code:

```
int calculate(){

    int number1;
    int number2;

    NumberDialog dialog;

    if(dialog.exec()){
        number1 = dialog.getInputNumber();
    }
    else number1 = 0;

    NumberDialog dialog2;
    if(dialog2.exec()){
        number2 = dialog.getInputNumber();
    }
    else number2 = 0;

    return number1+number2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is too broad and maybe primarily opinion-based. You are not showing code, so it's unclear what's your problem exactly. Moreover, two points demand two question, not a bigger one. First of all, I suggest you to start with a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: As @skypjack mentioned, you need to put some code here (to prove you have tried to fix it first!). Looks like you are using commercial version of `Qt`. Have you tried contacting Digia for the suggestions?

Comment: How about calling dialog->show() instead of dialog->exec(), and connecting the dialog's accepted() signal to a slot in your class that handles the result?  (Doing that will require some re-organization of your code, since the dialog's results won't be available within the same method that created/showed the dialog, but the resulting program will be more robust, because it will not be subject to the potential re-entrancy problems that come with running the Qt event loop recursively inside an exec() call)